# How to restore missing controls from toolbox in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

I am using windows7 and visual studio 2008. The datalist tool is missing from toolbox. How to restore the tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click in the Toolbox's panel you will get a popup menu with an option to reset the Toolbox. This will put your ToolBox back to the Factory settings, if you have adding anything manualy they will be reset. Also by right clicking in the same panel and selecting Choose Items, you can then select the .Net Framework Components Tab in the Choose Items Form and then select your missing Item from there.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to rightclick mouse on toolbox panel and "Reset toolbox"